# Prevent user from directly accessing a redirection URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

There are URLs which I use only for redirecting a user after a successful operation. (e.g. a "Thank you" page after submitting feedback).

The problem is that these pages can be accessed directly.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: does it really matter? the user would have to know the url, and there would be nothing on the page if the visited it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function thank_you() {
    if($this->referer() != 'some_url') {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

in the method you don't want to be accessible directly, just check to see if the referrer valid (i.e. the "contact form" for the "thank you" page.

If the referrer isn't the "contact form", you can redirect to wherever. If it matches, output the thank you page.

Comment: my url is dynamic paypal token and payer ID changed

Comment: and if is your referer https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-11W764021U1052947#pageState=EConsentAgreement&pageDispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8da6a0e86558d6153d7722c6eea13ecd7b&pageSession=wENIyr4Q_qBw2IVmpM8kAefjvns7ejY55iNpZB-99i1zV1ROJR0JRNnnlSq?

Answer (score 0):

You could create and store a random key upon completion of the operation, then simply verify that the key (using a combination or session, url, or db, your pick) is valid before redirecting.

Comment: explain further io is http referer a safer way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  [Controller::flash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aflash) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set a session variable on the page right before the redirect. Then on the "thank you" page, the variable is tested for and unset. If it was not there when the test was made, then redirect to an error page that says "This page cannot be accessed directly."

I have never used Cake, so that's a general PHP answer, not a Cake specific one.